# Pylint Error - no module named astroid

Tags: pylint

I've recently installed pylint on a windows 7  and when I run it I get the error:

```
Error executing PyLint: Command failed with error=None, status=1; stderr:
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pylint", line 3, in <module> 
   run_pylint() 
 File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pylint\__init__.py", line 20, in run_pylint 
from pylint.lint import Run 
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py", line 30, in <module> 
from pylint.checkers import utils #pylint: disable=unused-import
```

File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pylint\checkers__init__.py", line 47, in  
    from pylint.reporters import diff_string 
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pylint\reporters__init__.py", line 20, in  
    from pylint.utils import MSG_TYPES 
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pylint\utils.py", line 32, in  
    from astroid import nodes, Module 
ImportError: No module named astroid

I've followed the install instructions as best I can but can't seem to get past this.

Comment: how did you install pylint ? using pip/easy_install ? Astroid is a pylint dependencies. Above tools should install it automatically. If you install from source, download and install astroid as well (see https://bitbucket.org/logilab/astroid)

Answer (score 1):

Use this link to install pip properly [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

then do the **pip install pylint**

then do go through this note http://docs.pylint.org/installation.html#note-for-windows-users